# Spring-boot and aws elastic beanstalk: Following services are not running: application-web-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy spring-boot web application to aws elastic beanstalk.
i have added .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file in the root folder and also application.properties with server port 5000. But after I create new application with elastic beanstalk with Java i am getting this error:
Following services are not running: application-web-1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Same issue. AWS is notorious for being a nightmare to configure.

Comment: Try this, had created this blog in 2017, hope it’s still valid.   http://darpanmhatre.com/awselasticbeanstalk